# Android WorkManager DB out of proportion

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I wrote an app that requests data from a webserver on a regular basis. I usually do that only every few hours, but due to an error I requested updates every two minutes. This is still not an unreasonable frequency.

However, when I looked at the storage size of my app, I was surprised to see it pass the 100 MB barrier. It turned out, the app itself did not use the space, but the androidx.work.workdb which had 103 MB in size to manage the jobs. It basically kept all data for about a week.

I know, I can use `WorkManager.getInstance(context).pruneWork()` manually to clear the queue and the database will be small again, but should Android not prune automatically? What if I had a job every 10 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a high level note, if you have a job every 10 seconds, you are probably using WorkManager to solve a problem that should use a different solution.  If you do actually intend to use WorkManager, perhaps you should consider making chains of work or unique work.

As the documentation for `pruneWork` (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#pruneWork()) states, WorkManager prunes work after a sane amount of time, which is currently 7 days after completion.  This is to allow you to observe the status of finished workers.  If you need it to run more often, you can use `pruneWork`.

Comment: This job usually runs every few hours, therefore Work-Manager seems a good choice. According to Google it should be a good choice also for shorter intervals (For work that is deferrable and expected to run even if your device or application restarts, use WorkManager. ) I do not know what you mean by chains of work. My task schedules itself after finishing. And yes, I am pruning now regulary.